# Jenkins: How to call a function variable through shared library?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

A bit new to Jenkins and inherited this project that already has a pipeline. I am trying to make some improvements to it, and part of that is adding variables, however I cannot seem to access those variables.

The Jenkinsfile looks something like this:

```
def pipelineName(String variable1) {
  pipeline {
    // some code
    stage('Run shell command'){
      steps {
        sh '''
          echo "${variable1}"
        '''
      }
    }
    // some more code  
  }
}
pipelineName(variable1='Hello World')
```

However, when I run this I can see that echo ran but it doesn't actually print anything. I tried different combinations on the variable input, from removing the key to just having *Hello World* in there but it still did not work. What exactly can I do to have that String used in the shell command?

Comment: The call to the function should be just `pipelineName('Hello World')`, but the problem you have is with the `'''` which is a regular multi line string and does not support string interpolation, instead use  `"""`, for example: `sh """ echo ${variable1} """` or just `sh "echo ${variable1}"`. For more info see [Groovy String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Comment: Thank you, I will make the changes. If I use `"""` would I still be able to run multiple commands? The echo was just as an example, in reality the pipeline runs several scripts which take the variable as an input argument.

Comment: Yes, using `"""` will create a multiline GString that support string interpolation.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, let's see how it goes!